# bootstrap3 modal js undefined function

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a regular bootstrap-modal in HTML. I'm trying to show/hide it with javascript and i get undefined function.

I'm doing as the bootstrap documentation says, still i get undefined function on this row:

```
$("#registermodal").modal('show');
```

This is my HTML modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="registermodal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="registerDevice">Klargjøring</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="registerContent" class="form-group">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Enhetsnavn" class="col-lg-4 control-label">UUID</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uuid" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="AppleID1" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Apple-ID #1</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AppleID1" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="AppleIDPassword1" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Apple-ID Password #1</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AppleIDPassword1" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="AppleID2" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Apple-ID #2</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AppleID2" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="AppleIDPassword2" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Apple-ID Password #2</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AppleIDPassword2" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="SIMpin" class="col-lg-4 control-label">SIM-PIN</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SIMpin" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="losekod" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Låsekod</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="losekod" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Lokation</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <select size="6" class="form-control" id="lokationSelect">
                                <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
                                <option value="PDA">PDA</option>
                                <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
                                <option value="PDA">PDA</option>
                                <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
                                <option value="PDA">PDA</option>
                                <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
                                <option value="PDA">PDA</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="performKlargjoring()">Klargjøring</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the full error message? Is it `modal()` or jQuery that is undefined?

Answer (score 22):

One reason you may receive an undefined function would be if you have defined the jquery library more than once.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="registermodal" aria-hidden="true">
...
...
</div>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

The bootstrap library gets applied to the first jquery library but when you reload the jquery library, the original bootstrap load is lost (Modal function is in bootstrap).

One common cause of this issue is when including partial blocks of code within a web app as the same javascript file reference could appear in a complete page output in more than one location.
This is especially dangerous when your js definitions are scattered throughout your page ie, in the head, at the top of the body and at the bottom of the body (in a partial template).

Comment: "...if you have defined the jquery library more than once." That is the key. Thanks.

Comment: You saved my time! Thank you. "jquery library shouldn't be imported more than once."

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem changing

```
$(id).modal("show")
```

to

```
jQuery(id).modal("show").
```

Comment: Surprisingly, only this solution worked for me. Im using MeteorJS with ReactJS

Answer (score 2):

Add following script tag before declaring your own js file. This will solve the error.

```
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I added an on click to hide : [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/bj6Lp/1/)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/bj6Lp/)

It is not giving the undefined function like you say. I suggest wrapping your `$("#registermodal").modal('show');`

in a `$(document).ready(function(){});`

If that doesn't work (or if you already did that) I suggest adding your js script (or link) right before your `</body>`

Last case scenario, make sure you have bootstrap.min.js and jquery on your HTML page.

Comment: Wierd, i have it inside of a javascript method, can that cause any problem?

Comment: Can you show me the js method you are using? You need to make sure the method is called after the HTML page is finished loading.

Comment: It's inside of a function that gets called by a button click, so the HTML is loaded.

Comment: This is a stupid question but I'm getting the undefined error when I remove bootstrap.min.js file. Do you have it linked on your page? Here is a demo without the boostrap.min.js http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/bj6Lp/2/

Comment: None of the JS code in your demo is working, i updated to the latest bootstrap and jquery, still same problem.

Comment: I know, it's not supposed to work. Trying to recreate your undefined error in the console log. On the top of my head there is nothing else I can think of to fix your problem. Show me your method so I can test it in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56261/discussion-between-tobias-olofsson-and-grimbode).

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
$("#registermodal").modal();
```

Comment: Same problem, undefined function.

Comment: When providing a code that could help, it is better to explain why you expect it to work and to link to any relevant documentation.

Comment: This is not an solution!